# string is appending from previous statements

Tags: c++, string, c++14

I am going through C++ language code. and found an interesting thing.

See the code below -

```
void CharsAndStrings() {
    char s[] = "vaishnav";
    char s1[4] = {'s','h','i','v'};
    char s2[4] = {static_cast<char>('zz'),'y','x','v'}; // warning - Multi-character character constant

    printf("\n");
    printf("%s\n",s);
    printf("%s\n",s1);
    printf("%s\n",s2);    
}
```

Output is -

```
   vaishnav
   shivvaishnav
   zyxvshivvaishnav
```

Why var s1 value is merging with s and s2 with s1? I might have missing something here. If yes, Can someone point me out to that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Neither `s1` nor `s2` are `nul`-terminated strings - a requirement for using the `%s` format specifier.

Comment: Agree. Is this the known behaviour of string in C++ if not null terminated?

Comment: @shivam: It's not "known behavior"; it's undefined behavior to call most C++ APIs with a `char*` that is not NUL-terminated.

Comment: Without the nul-terminator it will try to read past the end of the string, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: even with a UB, shouldn't it consider "\n" in printf()?

Comment: No, there's no reasonable behavior you can expect, or rely on, when you have UB.

Comment: But I don't know why i got -1 on the post? Isn't this a valid question to ask. I think most novice people don't know about it.

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter; seems like a reasonable question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this declaration:

```
char s1[4] = {'s','h','i','v'};
```

calling:

```
printf("%s\n", s1);
```

invokes undefined behavior (UB), since `printf` requires the argument used by `%s` to be null-terminated.

UB means anything can happen. In your case, it appears the compiler placed the 3 arrays in the order `s2`, `s1`, and `s`, so printing out one, printed the other arrays as well. Of course, you shouldn't rely on this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a null terminator character for s1 and s4.
Try:

```
char s1[5] = {'s','h','i','v','\0'};
char s2[5] = {static_cast<char>('zz'),'y','x','v','\0'};
```

Comment: @cigien I think in C++ and C (and other languages) when char s[4] is declared: char[0 --> 3] can be used and char[4] is preserved for the nul terminator character. This is because this is a variable and not a data structure where it can store a value of it's length. That is how count or length or size know the length of the array, It start from the first character and keeps incrementing a counter until it find a null terminator character.

Comment: You appear to be thinking of c-style arrays. `char[4]` is *not* a pointer in c++, and it must contain exactly 4 chars.

Comment: @cigien Yes updated the answer. Didn't think about the difference between  C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

They are don't merge between themself. Char-sequence "shiv" and "zyxv" has no NULL symbol '\0'. When you call "print" it is going through the memory until met '\0'.
They have a close position in memory, that why you see other's strings.